# How do I set pagination options in the 'gh' command?

Tags: github

I can list reos for my org using:

```
gh api orgs/myorg/repos
```

But how can I set pagination options? I have look through [the docs](https://github.com/node-gh/gh#examples-19) and [issues](https://github.com/node-gh/gh/issues/590) and tried:

```
gh --per_page 100 api orgs/myorg/repos
```

and

```
gh api orgs/myorg/repos -f per_page=100
```

But neither work.

Answer (score 5):

OK found the answer to this a moment after I asked:

```
gh api orgs/myorg/repos --paginate
```

Hopefully this will be useful to others.